# MySQL - How to pick date from form and put it into table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, date

I'm trying to insert a date into a table on my database. I currently this HTML code to insert the date :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="date" name="date">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this PHP code to process the request :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $conn = new mysqli(MY_CONNECTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (date) VALUES (".$_POST['date'].")";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if(!$result) {
        die("SQL Error : ".$sql."<br>Error : ".$conn->error);
    }
}
?>
```

My table only contains an `ID` column and a `DATE` column that is a `DATE` type.
When I submit my form, SQL executes correctly but when my values are stored in the database the result for `DATE` is '0000-00-00'. I didn't change anything in the date format of my database.
I tried with a `print_r`  on my `$_POST` array end it prints out this :

```
Array ( [date] => 2017-04-04 [sell_Software_1] => Sell )
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the format of `$_POST['date']`? You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: The date must enclosed in singe quotes `VALUES ('".$_POST['date'].")'"; .
 `. But better you use prepared statements

Comment: @chris85 I use to filter my data using FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES. Is this a valid solution?

Comment: Sidenote: `<input type="date"` isn't supported by all browsers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Which browsers do not support this input type?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date - Firefox for one.

Comment: You should parameterize your query. I'm surprised anything `magic_quotes` is still around. `INSERT INTO my_table (date) VALUES (?)`. Prepare then then bind the `POST` value, and execute your query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @chris85 Thanks!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Do you know what happens if there are not supported input on a browser? Does it not show my input, or does it give me a strange value?

Comment: if you want it to be cross-browser, use a `text` type. You can also find yourself a datepicker that could also do the job but then you're going into JS territory.

Comment: @Hexadect See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date `browsers not supporting this type will display a simple text control`

Comment: @Barmar I don't think this is a duplicate of the question you linked to; that is asking about quoting data for insertion, this is about date formatting. Hexadect: In order to ensure consistent data format, you should use `<SELECT>` inputs in your form to constrain the date values, then assemble them into a proper date format for insertion.

Comment: @alanlittle He's formatting his date correctly, the problem is he didn't put it in quotes.